# Retrieve value from ItemProperties outlook : Operation failed

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm retrieving a custom properties previously added by my code in a MailItem.

I'm testing this VBA code with Outlook 2010.

```vb
Dim mailIndex
For mailIndex = objFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step - 1
    Dim property1
    Set property1 = GetMigrationProperty(objFolder.Items(mailIndex).ItemsProprieties)
    '... code goes on
Next
```

After the second iteration of the loop, the property1.Value is "Operation Failed" and it throws an exception.

I have this problem since I changed the loop type from For Each to an inversed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch! Is this your real code? This is multiple dot notation taken to its extreme.

Cache the Items variable before entering the loop and call Items(index) only once per iteration:

```
set Items = objFolder.Items
For mailIndex = Items.Count To 1 Step - 1
  Dim property1
  set Item = Items.Item(mailIndex)
  Set property1 = GetMigrationProperty(item.ItemsProprieties)
  '... code goes on
  set item = Nothing
Next
```

Comment: Also, if you call GetMigrationProperty more than once, cache the value of the item.ItemsProprieties collection and store it in a local variable. Reset it back to Northing at the loop end.

Comment: I see, this does work. May I ask why it's important to release the item object after each loop? If I understand correctly, the items object holds a reference to the mailItem, if we don't release it this reference will just be replaced by another one in the next iteration. Why is it important and how could it cause problems? I'm from a SharePoint/C# background that's why this looks weird to me.

Comment: If you are using multiple dot notation, the interpreter/compiler creates implicit variables to hold the intermediate variables, and you cannot explicitly access or release these variables. They are released when they go out of scope in VB script or whenever the GC feels like it in C#/VB.Net. This problem is much more profound in .Net languages compared to VB script.